# Something about Oauth2-server's JWT Access Tokens and JWT bearer

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, jwt

Uh..I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

### Q1.

---

I made reference to the [oauth2-server](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/jwt-access-tokens/)'s demo.

And using Memory storage can work But when I try Pdo storage.

I get the "500 Internal Server Error" and "Unexpected character (<) at position 1."

**Server**

```
 $storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array(
                                         'dsn' => $dsn, 
                                         'username' => $username,
                                         'password' => $password));

    $this->server = new OAuth2\Server($storage, array(
        'use_jwt_access_tokens' => true,
    ));
    $this->server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));
```

**Token**

```
 public function token_post(){
    $this->server->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
}
```

---

### Q2.

In [JWT Bearer page](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/grant-types/jwt-bearer/)

I can get access_token with demo,but this access_token don't work.

alway get "Failed" With resource page

**resource**

```
public function resource_get()
{
    if (!$this->server->verifyResourceRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())) {
        exit("Failed");
    }
    echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'You accessed my APIs!'));
}
```

---

### Q3.

I have no idea about what is the different between JWT Access Tokens and JWT Bearer to use?

### Remark

Sorry for bad English.

I use Google'translation to help me completion of these.
So i can't use realy correct description.

Sorry again for bad English.